# Hibernate 5 Spatial Unable to make DB connection

Tags: spring, maven, java-8, postgis, hibernate-5.x

I am struggling hard to get the DB Connection with my POST GIS spatial data.
Issue is with application context is not getting generated. Everytime JUnit gets failed. I am using Hibernate 5 as it is supporting Hibernate-Spatial as 
well as other java class mapping tools.

Below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringHibernateExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <postgresql.version>9.4-1201-jdbc4</postgresql.version>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <!-- <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>-->
        <hibernate.version>5.0.0.Final</hibernate.version> 

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--PostGreSQL Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and my application Context is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd">


    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bigbazar" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- PROPERTY CONFUGURER -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="com.bigbazar.util.PropertyConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:messages.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:MS-messages.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:configuration.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:sqlQueries.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="telenorTransactionManager" />

    <!-- Transaction Manager -->

    <bean id="telenorTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Declare a JPA entityManagerFactory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:persistence.xml"></property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="hibernatePersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBean" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

     <bean id="dataSourceBean" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}" /> <property 
        name="url" value="${databaseUrlEgis}" /> <property name="username" value="${liDatabaseUserName}" 
        /> <property name="password" value="${liDatabasePassword}" /> </bean> 

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
     <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
                    <property name="viewClass"
                        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
                    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">
                    <property name="prefixJson" value="true" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <util:list id="beanList">
                <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
            </util:list>
        </property>
    </bean> 




    <bean id="bigBazarDao" class="com.bigbazar.dao.impl.BigBazarDaoImpl" scope="singleton" />


    <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate" />





</beans>
```

My Persistence.xml is :

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="hibernatePersistenceUnit"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.bigbazar.persistent.UserDetails</class>
        <class>com.bigbazar.persistent.UserAddresses</class>    
        <class>com.bigbazar.persistent.UserMappedLocation</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect"/>

           <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
           <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:postgres"/>
           <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="userid"/>
           <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
           <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="5"/>

           <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
           <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>

           <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="5"/>

           <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

With the above settings, my application context is unable to build. I am getting following error while building the application.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.bigbazar.test.BaseTest
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.13/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.5.8/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:39,676] [main] (AbstractApplicationContext.java:513) - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@5c072e3f: startup date [Mon Aug 31 15:51:39 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:40,303] [main] (PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:172) - Loading properties file from class path resource [messages.properties]
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:40,315] [main] (PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:172) - Loading properties file from class path resource [MS-messages.properties]
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:40,323] [main] (PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:172) - Loading properties file from class path resource [configuration.properties]
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:40,328] [main] (PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:172) - Loading properties file from class path resource [sqlQueries.properties]
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:40,715] [main] (DriverManagerDataSource.java:133) - Loaded JDBC driver: org.postgresql.Driver
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:41,013] [main] (PersistenceUnitReader.java:207) - persistence.xml should be located inside META-INF directory; cannot determine persistence unit root URL for class path resource [persistence.xml]
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:41,024] [main] (LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:332) - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'hibernatePersistenceUnit'
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:41,101] [main] (LogHelper.java:31) - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: hibernatePersistenceUnit
    ...]
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:41,417] [main] (Version.java:37) - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.0.Final}
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:41,423] [main] (Environment.java:213) - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:41,431] [main] (Environment.java:317) - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:41,470] [main] (SpatialService.java:43) - HHH80000001: hibernate-spatial integration enabled : true
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:41,601] [main] (JavaReflectionManager.java:66) - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.0.Final}
 WARN [2015-08-31 15:51:42,211] [main] (JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:132) - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://152.144.227.172:5432:gisdb
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:42,263] [main] (Dialect.java:154) - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:42,392] [main] (LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:63) - HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:42,417] [main] (BasicTypeRegistry.java:138) - HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@5b529706
 INFO [2015-08-31 15:51:45,408] [main] (SchemaUpdate.java:101) - HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
 WARN [2015-08-31 15:51:45,447] [main] (SqlExceptionHelper.java:127) - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
ERROR [2015-08-31 15:51:45,450] [main] (SqlExceptionHelper.java:129) - No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://152.144.227.172:5432:gisdb
ERROR [2015-08-31 15:51:45,483] [main] (TestContextManager.java:322) - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@187eb9a8] to prepare test instance [com.bigbazar.test.BaseTest@726a6b94]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:319)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [BigBazar.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: hibernatePersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:121)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: hibernatePersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:877)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:805)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.ExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ExtractionContextImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:481)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://ip:port:db
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.ExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ExtractionContextImpl.java:62)
    ... 59 more
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 9.211 sec <<< FAILURE!
```

I am building the above application on Eclipse with JDK 1.8 and Spring 4.03 release.

Comment: Do not expose your URL at any time.. I strongly recommend you to remove the connection URL..

Comment: First your `hibernate.connection` properties are useless as you are injecting a `DataSource` with Spring. Second your stack trace is pretty clear `No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql` you haven't included the jdbc drivers for PostgreSQL.

Comment: @M. Deinum I have included it in my POM.xml. Please refer 
 <!--PostGreSQL Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Not according to your stack trace...

Comment: @M.Deinum Please provide me any inklink.

Comment: I also doubt that your URL is correct... A double `:` isn't really standard, imho the last `:` should be a `/`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I agree with you. I modify the  <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:postgres"/>
localhost with the real url. it is doesn't workout.

Comment: As I mentioned in my initial comment your `hibernate.connection` properties are useless due to the simple fact you are injecting a `DataSource`. You will get the same result with or without those properties. You need to change the URL in your properties file not your persistence.xml. Instead of dumping comments here I suggest you actually read them...